# get information from database sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how to get an information from the database. I want to execute this line

```
String nom = db.execSQL("select name from person where id='+id+'");
```

Can any one correct me this line to get the name of person from the table person

Comment: You should have [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Using+Database+in+Android) StackOverflow before posting the question.

Comment: try this line db.execSQL("select name from person where id='"+id+"'");

Comment: @ganapathy: wrong, look at the answers to see why...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Please try this if your id is integer datatype.**

```
public String getResult(int id)
{
    String name = null;
    try
    {
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select name from person where id="+id, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name; 
}
```

**Pease try this if your id is String datatype.**

```
 public String getResult(String id)
{
    String name = null;
    try
    {
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select name from person where id=" + "\""+id+"\"", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name; 
}
```

Comment: Little hint: name is not an int :)

Comment: Very good, well-written answer which was exactly what I needed.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = ?", new String[] { id });
cursor.moveToFirst();
String nom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

this should be the easiest way (not tested, but you should get the idea).

It also looks like you have no idea how android handles database access, so I recommend to look at least at the [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) class.

`execSQL()` documentation:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.