# select query in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String temp_address="nothing";
    try
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails INTO"+temp_address+"WHERE bookpath=?";
        db.execSQL(selectQuery, new String[] { fileName });
        System.out.println(temp_address+" result of select Query");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e+" is the error here");

    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }
```

Logcat

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "bookpath": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails INTOnothingWHERE bookpath=?
```

i just want to take the result of the above query so that the string stored in lastchapter is available in temp_address
please help

i am new to android sqlite database please help

Comment: now this error
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTO": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails INTO nothing WHERE bookpath=?

Comment: see my update and try this way

Comment: your query should be: String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails INTO "+temp_address+" WHERE bookpath=?";

Comment: For any query,
this helped me 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5498403/2542175

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are SQL syntax problems and you'll need to use a `Cursor` to retrieve query results, for example with `rawQuery()`:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails WHERE bookpath=?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { fileName });
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    temp_address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastchapter"));
}
c.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct your query with below: add space at `WHERE` Cause

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails WHERE bookpath=? ";
```

**Update:** go with `rawQuery()` becoz it's return `Cursor` with results

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails WHERE bookpath=? ";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { fileName });
 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
 temp_address = c.getString(0);
 }
  c.close();
```

And for more information go to this: http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/accessing-data-with-android-cursors/

Answer (score 3):

The logcat said it all, you've forgot spaces. To get data into the string:

```
String temp_address="nothing";
String[] args = new String[] { fileName };
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails WHERE bookpath=?", args);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    temp_address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastchapter"));
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the first error is solved but now
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTO": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails INTO nothing WHERE bookpath=?

i think there is a syntax error in my select query, i just want to get the value in temp_address